# Question about meaning of "community" and "interior features: 2 story" in a context of renting a house

Tags: word-meaning

> Other room
>
> - laundry: **community**
> - rooms: living room
>
> **Interior** features
>
> - 2 story
> - security features: **gated community**

1. My first concern has to do with the word "interior" . When it say "interior features 2 story", is it saying that it is a duplex? Two separate rooms in two stories? Could you answer in simple English?
2. My second concern is about the meaning of the word **community". What does each community mean? First highlighted community and the second highlighted community? Could you answer in simple English, please?

Comment: I'm not really sure on this one. However, I think *story* (or *storey*) means level. (*Duplex* could be ambiguous, imo. I think the ad you got means two levels.) I take this *community* as *shared*; so, you got a sort of "shared" laundry, outside of your apartment or rooms. "Gated community" probably means you have a shared main door, gate, or entry. (I imagine a big village with a big front gate, security guards walking around.)

Comment: @Damkerng T - laundry in share? A shared washing machine? Or a shared dryer ? Or a shared room with separate washing machine ?

Comment: Sorry to ask these details but I am indeed in need of your help. Thank you.

Comment: It's hard for me to say anything for sure with only what I have (other room [sic]--laundry: community). However, I'm quite certain that the room (or the place or the area) where the laundry stuff happens is shared or commonly used. This [image search](http://www.google.com/search?q=community+laundry&tbm=isch) might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

> laundry: community

That probably means there is a laundry room that is shared by everyone in the complex. There would surely be multiple washing machines in there.

> 2 story

That means there are two floors. A lower floor and an upper floor. It's impossible to say how many rooms there are based on the text you have shown us. It's impossible also to say whether it is a duplex building or not.

> security features: gated community

A gated community has a gate at the front, which is meant to prevent or discourage random people from getting inside. What that means exactly depends on the particular place. It could mean for instance that you need a special remote control device for opening the gate to drive inside.